# Converting a list of dicts to a single dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

For below content how can I get "a_id" value and its "b_id" value based on "name" validation.

```
[
{
    "name": "name1",
    "a_id": "12345",
    "b_id": "0d687c94c5f4"
},
{
    "name": "name2",
    "a_id": "67890",
    "b_id": "0d687c94c5f4"
},
{
    "name": "name3",
    "a_id": "23857",
    "b_id": "9ec34be3d535"
},
{
    "name": "name4",
    "a_id": "84596",
    "b_id": "9ec34be3d535"
},
{
    "name": "name5",
    "a_id": "d82ebe9815cc",
    "b_id": null
}
```

]

I have used for two values like

```
{result['a_id']: result['name'] for result in data}
```

but for third value it won't let me do this if I use like this.

```
{result['a_id']: result['name'], result['b_id']: result['name'] for result in data}
```

what is the correct syntax.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you'd like your output to look like?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. what COLDSPEED posted is what I am looking. Had issues with reply box and couldn't post quickly but I got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a *dict comprehension* with a nested loop should do the trick:

```
data = {result[k] : result['name'] for result in data for k in ('a_id', 'b_id')}
```

You can add as many keys as you want. If it makes more sense, declare your keys outside, in a variable `keys`:

```
keys = ('a_id', 'b_id', ...)
data = {result[k] : result['name'] for result in data for k in keys}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. You actually answered my question. I have one question on the output I get.

when I use 

{result['b_id']: result['name'] for result in data} 

I am getting only 3 values instead of 5. 0d687c94c5f4, 9ec34be3d535 and null. If you notice there are duplicate "b_id"s. But I do need those instead of getting filtered. Sorry I am not sure if it is ok to ask further into a different question or I have to post a new question.